# How do my next line of code will be executed even if the page load is not completed after a button click?

Tags: promise, protractor

I have a situation like below.
I am passing the url and login page is appearing. After clicking in the Sign In button one certificate window will come up(windows popup kind of thing). The page will load for infinite time until and and unless you click on the OK button of the certificate popup.
As the page is still loading (i.e there are some console call happening) the control wont go to the next line of code where i have written logic to click on the OK button. Hence you cannot click on the OK button of the certificate window until the page load completes. So my point is how do i click on the OK button forcefully even if the page is loading infinitely.

I tried browser.refresh() also nothing is working for me. I believe the reason is due to the control flow of protractor. i.e until and unless the last promise resolves the next command wont be executed.

I would be much happy if somebody help me on the above scenario.

Thanks,
Sudhansu

Comment: try waitForAngularEnabled(false)

Comment: Please let me know where to add the line waitForAngularEnabled(false)

Comment: before you click the sign in button.

Comment: it('TC01 - Launch application', function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.driver.get("url");
        browser.findElement(by.xpath("//!*[text() ='log in']")).click();
         // Here i want to write the logic to click on the OK button of the certificate 
    });

Comment: so first of all, ignoreSynchronization is deprecated, but right now it actually calls browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false); so then I think what I suggested won't help (but if you want to try it, it could be the first line like you have it).  browser.get should suffice, not browser.driver.get. Also, rather than browser.findelement, I think just element(by.xpath ..). Then I think wait for the popup to be present, switch to it, and click ok (several questions last couple of weeks about how to do that)

Comment: its a window popup .. you can not switch to that... here the main issue is after clicking on Sign In button the page is infinite loading with that certifcaite popup. And you know whenever the page load is not completed then you can proceed with the next line. I hope you understand my issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176608/discussion-between-jeremy-kahan-and-mfsi-sudhansu).